# Can we create local Docker IoT containers for a SMACK-like environment with DC/OS and push them to our AWS VPC - if so, how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dcos, vpc, lambda-architecture

In planning out a our [Lambda architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/), for both real-time and batch processing, I see we will need several m3.xlarge instances (see [CloudFormation SMACK stack template](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/04/smack-stack-hands/)) using DC/OS.

As not to incur too much cost for a POC, is there an approach that would allow us to create local Docker containers then deploy them to our VPC, launching only for testing?